# Locate the script / line using Flash

Tags: security, flash, firefox, warnings, detect

Starting with Firefox 39, the browser is very strict about the usage of Flash within Websites ...

So out of the blue, my web app that I'm not aware of using flash at all, all of a sudden provokes this message in Firefox 39 ("Firefox has prevented the execution of the vulnerable plugin "Adobe Flash" ").

I want to completely get rid of any flash, wether it's in my code (accidentially) or in any other third-party library I'm using.

So is there a way of detecting the script / line of code that makes Firefox think my App is making use of flash? I think my App isn't / should not need to be using Flash ...

Thanks for any hint where to search and "hunt down" Flash.

Comment: I don't know really if I understood your question or not, but are looking just for the line that insert an swf object in your HTML code ?

Comment: Essentially I want to know what triggers the warning in Firefox, since I was pretty sure that we don't use flash anywhere in our project.

Comment: I already searched all of our (own) code for occurrances of "swf", "flash", "flashmovie", "application/x-shockwave-flash" and there didn't show up any ... Also, I searched the DOM using jQuery for dom nodes with tags  like 'object' or 'embed', using $('object') and $('embed') ... but it returned an empty array ... So maybe there is another trigger in firefox that shows the message to block flash, maybe a simple whitelist of URLs?

Comment: If firefox show you the message, so sure you have an swf file which has been loaded ! You can use the "Network monitor" on the developer tools to see the loaded file. If your page is online, you can put its link to see with you.